# SQL results operation question

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know I missasked the question, and that's probably the reason I can't find the solution myself:

How do I take a result in a stored procedure and and change the data such as

```
    if column1 = AAA then 
      column1=Hello
    else if column1 = BBB then 
     column1 = goodbye
```

and have the data return with the new values?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can get to the content of the stored procedure, you should change it to a table-valued function instead - if possible, an inline one (because that has a much higher chance of being able to be optimised).

This will let you query the results and change it as needed:

```
SELECT CASE column1 
         WHEN 'AAA' THEN 'Hello' 
         WHEN 'BBB' THEN 'goodbye' 
       END as NewColumn,
  ,*
FROM dbo.yourNewFunction() as t;
```

If you can't do this, and are very much stuck with a stored procedure, you could wrap it up in OPENROWSET:

```
SELECT CASE column1 
         WHEN 'AAA' THEN 'Hello' 
         WHEN 'BBB' THEN 'goodbye' 
       END as NewColumn,
  , *
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI','Server=.;Trusted_Connection=Yes;','EXEC dbo.YourProc') as t;
```

This is a way to treat the output of a procedure as a table expression, but if you can do it without the procedure, that's better still.

Answer (score 1):

Use the CASE statement:

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN column1 = 'AAA' THEN 'Hello' 
         WHEN column1 = 'BBB' THEN 'goodbye' 
         ELSE ... -- optional
       END
```

Answer (score 1):

these two queries:

UPDATE table_name SET column1='Hello' WHERE column1='AAA'
UPDATE table_name SET column1='goodbye' WHERE column1='BBB'

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to rename everything starting with my to your actual table names

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myProc
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE myTable 
        SET Column1 = 
            CASE
            WHEN 'AAA' THEN 'Hello' 
            WHEN 'BBB' THEN 'goodbye'
            END
    WHERE Column1 in ('AAA','BBB')
    OUTPUT myTable.myIDColumn, INSERTED.Column1
END
```

Updates the table and returns only the updated records once you

```
EXEC myProc
```

Reference
1. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx